# Enlargement of unit cell by ordering wave vector for a square (or triangular) lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

For a square lattice we have lattice vectors $\vec{a_1}=(a,0)$ and $\vec{a_2}=(0,a)$. If we introduce an ordering by a wave vector $\vec{Q}=(\pi/a,\pi/a)$, the unit cell is doubled and the new lattice vectors are $\vec{a_1}+\vec{a_2}$ and $\vec{a_1}-\vec{a_2}$.

One can see this clearly by drawing the lattice but how to formally show the above?
What relation would the new lattice vectors obey if given a general $\vec{Q}$.

I am working on a problem in which I have a triangular lattice and have an incommensurate ordering vector.
How would one calculate the new lattice vectors for the enlarged unit cell for a general given ordering wave vector?